# How do I make my program loop as to print the multiple positions of one word?

Tags: python, loops

I need help with finding multiple of the same word in a list and printing positions of them
 this is my code so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0JKF.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please paste your code here, and ask a question about a specific problem you are having.  We try to help, but it isn't nice to make us do the leg-work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(word, word_list):
    return [i for i,w in enumerate(word_list) if w == word]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I enjoy leg-work.  In your `else` block, you print that the sentence was found as many times as it was found.  You also use `Split_Sent.index()` as many times as it was found.  `Split_Sent.index(something)` given the same `something` will always return the same answer.  You should change your `else` block to something more like this:

```
else:
    print("Your word '%s' was found in your sentence %d times.  The following are the numbered positions of which:")
    index = 0
    for i in range(Counted_Word):
        index += Split_Sent[index + 1:].index(Lower_Word)
        print index
```